# Clean url with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, clean-urls

I can't use any of the gems for creating clean Urls in rails. Instead I am rolling out my own implementation. I have created the following entry in routes.rb

```
match "/:slug" => "cleanurls#index"
```

Where cleanurl is a controller for handling all such requests. In the cleanurl controller:

```
class CleanurlsController < ApplicationController


 def index

  slug  = params['slug']

  url = Url.where(:slug => slug).first

  case(url.url_type) 

       when 'profile'

                 user_id = url.id.to_i
                 @profile = Profile_info.getProfileDetails(user_id)
                 render '/profiles/index'
       end

 end

end
```

I have created the table `urls` which stores the `slug`,`id` (as relevant) and the `type of page`. Right now I have only the profile page to deal with but in the future I will have different types of pages with clean urls.

My first Question:

1) Is this implementation the right approach? And is this okay from a performance perspective given the tables have all the right indexes.

I am making the profile url like this:

```
    def self.makeProfileUrl(id,name)

     name = name.strip.titleize

     extension = User.where(:name => name).count - 1

     slug = name.split(" ").join("-")

     if extension != 0
        slug += "-#{extension}"
     end

        Url.create(:slug => slug, :id => id.to_i, :url_type => 'profile')

   end
```

I am using extension to append a count in case their are users who share the same name.

Question:

Is this the right way to create the slug and ensure it being unique? Fetching the count of a name from the other table does not seem right.

Comment: Why can't you use gems? Hint: you are already using many of them by using Rails.

Comment: I use a lot of gems and I am not vary of them in general. For this specific case however I am looking for my own implementation.

Comment: But why solve a problem that already has been solved? I mean unless you do this whole thing for educational purposes, there is no reason to despise a well tested gem.

Comment: Well the friendly id gem generates the url like this(from github)
GET http://localhost:3000/users/joe-schmoe

Whereas I would want it at 
GET http://localhost:3000/joe-schmoe

Comment: That was the first reason why I decided to roll out my own.

Comment: Ok i see. But i dont like this solution. Be aware that you might get problems when two records of different types generate the same slug!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answering the question #1:**

I don't know the details of what's your overall goal, but if you'd like
to have such URLs that are based on records from the database - then yes: it's
a good approach.

**Answering question #2 (regarding slugs):**

I'd rather use something much more elaborate and well tested like:
https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

**My 50 cents about some other things:**

Is this one of your first projects in Ruby/Rails? If so - congratulations! :)
I'm asking because I noticed that you're using camel case here and there...

Also:

```
user_id = url.id.to_i
```

Why do you call this #to_i method here? Did you set up this id as a string
or something?

Hope this helps

Comment: I am aware of friendly id but I might want to use a part of it just to create the url rather than routing it. 

Yes, this is my first RAILS project, besides I love camel case. Makes things readable. 

The particular snippet of code was copied, I was getting the id from a GET parameter where I wrote it. I do a conversion to integer for security reasons, to ensure only numbers are being passed where they are expected to be passed.

Comment: @VarunJain of course using camel case is not forbidden, but the convention in Ruby is to use camel case only for class names. Using camel case elsewhere somewhat brands you a rookie.